# HtmlService Spreadsheet form refresh

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a form ModalForm on a Google Sheet that inserts rows into the sheet. It's been working fine for months. Starting last week after submitting the form the form disappears and doesn't re-display. I'm not sure why. It executes the insert into the spreadsheet fine. I just never get the form back to insert the next record.

In my Index file, the form code:

```
<form id="myReceiveForm" name="receive" onsubmit="writeLine()">
  Scanner Name : <input id="user" name="user" type="text" required  /> <br> <br>
  Reference Number: <input id="reference" name="reference" type="text" required  /> <br> <br>
  Location:         <input id="location" name="location" type="text" pattern="[A-Z]{1,3}\-[A-Z]{1,2}\-\d{1,3}\-\d{1,2}" title="Location not in correct format." required/> 
  <button type="button" value="change" onclick="changeLocation()" >Change Location</button><br> <br>
  Product SKU:      <input id="sku" name="sku" type="text" value="" autofocus /> <br> <br> 
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">


function onSuccess() {

    document.getElementById("sku").value = '';
    document.getElementById("sku").focus();
    return false;

}

function onFailureM(error) {

     alert("Invalid Sku");
    //alert("SKU" + document.getElementById("sku ").value +" doesn't exist.");
     document.getElementById("sku").value = '';
    document.getElementById("sku").focus();

}


window.writeLine = function () {


 google.script.run
   .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
   .withFailureHandler(onFailureM)
   .appendRowstoSheet(document.forms[0]);
} 

</script>
```

In My .gs file:

```
function openReceiving() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
           SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, '3PL RECEIVING');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `onsubmit="writeLine()"` from the upper form tag.  Change the submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" >
```

to a regular button with an event:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onmouseup="writeLine()">
```

This should fix the problem.  On Nov. 12th, 2015 Google migrated to IFRAME mode.

> All new scripts will default to IFRAME sandbox mode unless NATIVE mode is explicitly specified.

[Google Apps Script Sunset Scedule](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/sunset)

This is what probably caused your problem.  The form submit causes a form tag to disappear.  This is expected behavior that has been in place for a long time in regular HTML.  But for a long time, HTML Service overrode that behavior.  Now, IFRAME mode is more like regular HTML behavior.

In the SKU input field, try adding an `onchange` attribute if you need the form to submit after the last field is updated:

```
<input id="sku" name="sku" type="text" value="" autofocus onchange="writeLine()"/>
```

[onchange Event - Reference information](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)

[List of all the events](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp)

Comment: One problem I'm having now is that I the last field in my form the data is entered by using a scanner. The scanner sends a carriage return after scanning. I need this to submit the form. It did it in the old one. What event would I need for that? As I'm not using a keyboard or mouse to physically push the submit button. Thanks.

Comment: Good question.  Try using the `onchange=""` event.  See updated answer.